# setOnClickListner () in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, onclick

If there are so many buttons in the screen (UI) and need to do the seperate functions, for this kind of scenario can we use setOnClickListner for each button or what's the optimize way to handle this ?

Comment: I think `ButterKnife` is a good way to solve your question.

Answer (score 3):

I normally do something along the lines of this:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

Private Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        Button[] buttons = new Button[] {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5};
        final String[] functions= new String[] {"options", "exit", "credits", "more", "pictures"};
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            final String function = functions[i].toString();
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    StartIntent(function);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private StartIntent (String function){
        Intent i;

        switch (function) {
            case options:
                i = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
                break;
            case options:
                i = new Intent(this, ExitActivity.class);
                break;
            case options:
                i = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
                break;
            case options:
                i = new Intent(this, MoreActivity.class);
                break;
            case options:
                i = new Intent(this, PicturesActivity.class);
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("StartIntent", "invalid function");
                return;
        }

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This will open different intents depending on what button you click, but it really depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Make your activity implement `View.onClickListener` and switch over the sent `View` id:

```
public class YourActivity extends ... implements View.OnClickListener
{   
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.yourFirstButton:
                ...
                break;

            case R.id.yourSecondButton:
                ...
                break;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to implement the View.OnClickListener.
And in the onClick() you can use the switch case for buttons.

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.Button1 :  //Your button code
                         break;
  case R.id.Button2 : // Your Second Button code
                          break;
     .
     .
     .
     .
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this procedure if you have too many buttons in your UI

In your design page (XML) use 'onClick()' method for each activity with the same name. Here in my case it is    **android:onClick="onClickButton"**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onClickButton"
android:textColor="@color/icons" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onClickButton"
android:textColor="@color/icons" />
```

Now in Activity page use method like this,

```
public void onClickButton(View v)
{
switch(v.getId())
 {
   case R.id.button1:
       //do your work related to on click button1
   break;

   case R.id.button2:
      //do your work related to on click button2
   break;
   ....

 }
}
```

You can use any number of buttons in the case.
Hope that helps!